# How to prevent value can not be Null during c# SQLBulkcopy Processing

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, sqlbulkcopy

I am processing a CSV file using ASP.NET C# and it works if I assign 0 to fields that = "". But if I try to replace with " " or "/t" then I get a value can not be Null when inserting into the database.

Here is the C# code in question:

```
while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
{
    var fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
    //Making empty value as space to prevent DBNull errors during import/ export
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
    {
        if (fieldData[i] == "" )
        {
            fieldData[i] = " "; // 0 or any other character but whitespace works.
        }
    }
```

Where fieldData[i] = " " I would like to know do I insert ascii or unicode for space into the database for space because simply providing = " " gives me the null error?

EDIT: This is how I am ultimately sending the data to the database:

```
   static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData)
{
        string cc = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LEDRSTestConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(cc))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(cc, SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
                s.BatchSize = 66;

                // Map the Excel and SQL Columns
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Locality Identifier", "Locality Identifier");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Locality Child Identifier", "Locality Child Identifier");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("SSN", "SSN");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Student Identifier", "Student Identifier");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Last Name", "Last Name");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("First Name", "First Name");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Middle Name", "Middle Name");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("Suffix", "Suffix");
                s.ColumnMappings.Add("OASIS CLIENT ID", "OASIS CLIENT ID");


                s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);

            }

        }
```

}

Comment: If that column cannot be null, there probably is (or at least there *should* be) a good reason why it cannot be left empty. Replacing it with a space seems abusive. You should (re)consider why that column is empty in the csv, and what that means and how to handle that situation.

Comment: It's not just one column. There are several fields within certain columns that also meet the = "" criteria and I need something to replace the empty value. so that null is not inserted and the error is not thrown. The database design specifications called for not null but that column now has blanks needed to go in so it doesn't throw that error.

Comment: If you really want a space, you could try replacing with `"' '"`. How are you sending it to the database?

Comment: Thinking about it, it sounds suspiciously as if the column is a numeric datatype. What are the datatypes involved?

Comment: I am working with both Int and Varchar as non-nullable datatypes for several columns. I am sending the data to the database using a method that looks something what I edited in my question above.

Comment: It looks like I will just have to end up making sure the data is in the correct format before the upload process starts to avoid the errors in the first place. That seems like the best route to take rather than trying to edit the data at run-time during upload.